# Using weak maximum principle to prove continuous dependence of the boundary data?

Tags: elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces, problem-solving, p-laplace

I am currently looking at the following ingomogenous Dirichlet problem over an open, bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with continuous boundary:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
 -\operatorname{div} (\sigma |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u) = f &\quad  \text{in } \Omega\\
u = g &\quad \text{in } \partial\Omega
\end{cases} 
\end{align}

My initial conditions are the right side $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ and the boundary condition $g \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. I already proved that a unique solution $u \in W^{1,p}_g := \{ v \in W^{1,p}(\Omega): v - g \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) \}$ exists. This solution is also the minimizer of the functional:

\begin{align}
J(v) = \frac{1}{p}\int_{\Omega} \sigma |\nabla v|^p~dx - \int_{\Omega} fv~dx
\end{align}

So for the Frechet derivate of $J(u)$ we have:

\begin{align}
J^{ \prime}(u)\phi = \int_{\Omega} \sigma|\nabla u_1|^{p-2} \nabla u_1 \nabla \phi~d x - \int_{\Omega} f_1 \phi ~dx = 0 \quad \text{for all $\phi \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$}
\end{align}

But now I am trying to figure out how to prove, that this problem is continuous depending on $f$ and $g$.

I think I got the $f$-part:

Let $u_1$, $u_2$ be the solutions for $f_1$, $f_2$ on the right side of the equation. Since they have the same values on the boundary we have $u_1 - u_2 \in W^{1,p}_0$. Because they minimize the functional, for the frechet derivates we have

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \sigma|\nabla u_1|^{p-2} \nabla u_1 \nabla \phi~d x = \int_{\Omega} f_1 \phi ~dx\\
\int_{\Omega} \sigma|\nabla u_2|^{p-2} \nabla u_2 \nabla \phi~d x = \int_{\Omega} f_2 \phi ~dx
\end{align}

This is true for all $\phi \in W^{1,p}_0$. Therefore it is espacially true for $u_1 - u_2 \in W^{1,p}_0$:

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \sigma|\nabla u_1|^{p-2} \nabla u_1 \nabla (u_1 - u_2)~d x = \int_{\Omega} f_1 (u_1 - u_2) ~dx\\
\int_{\Omega} \sigma|\nabla u_2|^{p-2} \nabla u_2 \nabla (u_1 - u_2)~d x = \int_{\Omega} f_2 (u_1 - u_2) ~dx
\end{align}

Combined we have

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} (\sigma|\nabla u_1|^{p-2} \nabla u_1 - \sigma|\nabla u_2|^{p-2} \nabla u_2)\nabla (u_1 - u_2)~d x = \int_{\Omega} (f_1 - f_2) (u_1 - u_2) ~dx
\end{align}

For the left side I have proved an estimation which yields
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \alpha |\nabla u_1 - \nabla u_2|^p ~dx \leq \int_{\Omega} (\sigma|\nabla u_1|^{p-2} \nabla u_1 - \sigma|\nabla u_2|^{p-2} \nabla u_2)\nabla (u_1 - u_2)~d x
\end{align}

with an $\alpha > 0$ (this estimation is not obvious, but valid). For the right side we have (considering we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so whe have the continuous embedding $W^{1,p}$ in $L^2$):

\begin{align}
\alpha \| u_1 - u_2 \|^p_{W^{1,p}_0}=\int_\Omega (f_1 - f_2) (u_1 - u_2) ~dx\\
\leq \|f_1 - f_2\|_{L^2}~\|u_1 - u_2|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \|f_1 - f_2\|_{L^2}~\|u_1 - u_2\|_{W^{1,p}_0}
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
\| u_1 - u_2 \|_{W^{1,p}_0} \leq C \|f_1 - f_2\|^{\frac{1}{p}}_{L^2}
\end{align}

meaning that $u_1 \rightarrow u_2$ for $f_1 \rightarrow f_2$... It seems correct for me, but is it?

Nevertheless I find the $g$-part more complicated... What I "got" so far, after some research:

If $u$ and $u_k$ are the solutions regarding boundary data $g$ and $g_k$, they both solve the variational PDE, so

\begin{align}
 \int_{\Omega} \sigma|\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u \nabla \phi~d x = \int_{\Omega} f \phi~dx\\
 \int_{\Omega} \sigma|\nabla u_k|^{p-2} \nabla u_k \nabla \phi~d x = \int_{\Omega} f \phi~dx
\end{align}

since the right side is the same, combining this we get

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \sigma(|\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u - |\nabla u_k|^{p-2} \nabla u_k)  \nabla \phi~d x = 0
\end{align}

Thanks to the vector inequality for $y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$

\begin{align}
\alpha \left|  |z|^{p-2} z - |y|^{p-2}y  \right| \geq | z - y | ^{p-1}
\end{align}

we have the following estimate:
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} | \nabla (u - u_k)|^{p-2} \nabla (u - u_k) \nabla \phi~dx\\
\leq \alpha \int_{\Omega} \left(  |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u - |\nabla u_k|^{p-2} \nabla u_k \right) \nabla \phi ~dx
\end{align}

Altogether we have

$$
\int_{\Omega} | \nabla (u - u_k)|^{p-2} \nabla (u - u_k) \nabla \phi~dx \leq 0 \quad \text{for all $\phi \in W^{1,p}$}
$$

This means, that $u - u_k \in W^{1,p}_{g - g_k}(\Omega)$ solves the following partial differntial inequality:

\begin{cases}
 -\operatorname{div} (\sigma |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u) \leq 0 &\quad  \text{in } \Omega\\
u = g - g_k &\quad \text{in } \partial\Omega
\end{cases}

My intention is to somehow use a weak maximum principle...
In "The Maximum Principle" [Patrizia Pucci, James Serrin] I found the following theorem (p-laplace is a special case):

[snapshot of the theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeIQG.jpg)

So now I know $u - u_k |_{\partial\Omega} = g - g_k$.
We know that every constant function is a solution of the PD-Inequality above. Therefore I was tinking of something like "take a function which is constantly ess sup($g - g_k$) on $\Omega$... But it is not clear, that $g - g_k \in L^\infty(\Omega)$. But then I thought about the Sobolev Embedding in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$:

$$
W^{1,p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow C(\overline{\Omega}) \quad \text{if } p > n
$$

Now I am not sure... Clearly my domain is in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but can we see the boundary $\partial\Omega$ as a domain in $\mathbb{R}$? Because then if I say $g - g_k \in W^{1,p}(\partial\Omega)$, I can choose $c = \max\limits_{x \in \partial\Omega} g - g_k$. Then I pick a function $u_c = C$. Because its constant, it also solves the PD-Inequality above. Furthermore I would have

$$
u - u_k \leq u_c \quad \text{in } \partial\Omega
$$

because of the weak maximum principle I would get
$$
u - u_k \leq C = \max_{x \in \partial\Omega} g - g_k
$$

this looks like $u_k \rightarrow u$ if $g_k \rightarrow g$, but I am very unsure about it and can't formulate it cleanly... I would be very thankful if someone could give me some hints and help me!